# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: glowcoder]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

**Update: January 16, 2017**

We'd like to welcome Kate Paulk to the team. She graciously agreed to step into the role filling an empty slot in the moderation team

[image: Kate Paulk]

Please join me in welcoming her to the team.  Also, please give a big thanks to [Bruce McLeod](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/166/bruce-mcleod), who served 5+ years as a moderator to the site, prior to stepping down.

---

**Update: August 15, 2017**

We'd like to welcome alecxe to the team. He agreed to step into the role filling an empty slot in the moderation team

[image: alecxe]

Please join me in welcoming him to the team.  Also, please give a big thanks to [testerab](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/103/testerab), who served 6+ years as a moderator to the site, prior to stepping down.

Comment: +1, though I wonder how Alan is missing

Comment: and ya, testeab, glowcoder would you please keep your real pics if not a trouble for you. I definitely want to see the group moderators...

Comment: @Tarun: Like the post says, this isn't meant to be a slight against anyone - there are lots of good folks here on SQA. And the last thing we want is to bind up *all* the top users in moderation duties!

Comment: @Tarun it's entirely possible it was offered to him and he declined it. And this is only a temporary thing - in a few weeks you can nominate him, and he can accept the nomination and run, or he can decline. As far as real pics go, I respectfully decline. I'd prefer my upvotes be for quality posts - if you saw my real pic, you'd have to upvote for the sexiness of the 32x32 pixels alone, which wouldn't be fair.

Comment: Just playing. Honestly though, I'm rather fond of my gravitar. :-)

Comment: @Shog9, @glowcoder ok ok

Comment: @glowcoder - QA has good sense of humor also :)

Comment: Thanks Bruce and goodluck Kate Paulk :)

Comment: Congrats @alecxe and good luck!

Comment: @testerab thank you for all the work you've done on SQA! Hope it will go public in the future. Hope to see you around as well.

Answer (score 3):

Cool!  Good luck, Bruce, testerab, glowcoder.  I promise to be respectful and understanding. Or at least until you become full Moderators.  Once that happens all promises become null and void.  :-)

Comment: Congratulations to our new moderators.